# Derive channel type from pyopencl.Image object

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, pyopencl

I created an `pyopencl.Image` object via:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
image = cl.image_from_array(ctx, np.ones((16, 16), dtype=np.uint8))
```

How can I obtain the image channel type information (here, `cl.channel_type.UNSIGNED_INT8`)? I want to implement a generic downloading function that returns a numpy array given an `Image`.

I tried two approaches:

Using `Image.element_size` gives me the byte size of a single element, however I can't map the element size to a data type (float32 and int32 have the same element size, for instance).

`Image.format` returns a `cdata 'struct _cl_image_format &'`. Querying either of the fields `image_channel_data_type` and `image_channel_order` returns 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an [answer](https://lists.tiker.net/pipermail/pyopencl/2016-December/002255.html) via the PyOpenCl mailing list.

It turned out that the functionality of returning `Image.format` was incorrect. This has been fixed in the [github repo](https://github.com/pyopencl/pyopencl/commit/87fec9cba500a6aff47b7c0367c7663b4938404f).